# How to fetch data in MVC.net Entity framework which have page but not have any controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am making an application in .net entity framework in this i have a page for side bar and i want to fetch data on that side bar but problem is that ,that side bar does not contains any controller ,apart from sidebar i have three controller home,Admin,Sub admin how to fetch data to side bar from one of these controller how to do that please help me.

Comment: You can still use ajax to populate data on your sidebar. this is just one of the many ways

Comment: is there any refrence link for that ?